# Creating a single disabled css class for multiple classes

Tags: css, angular, disabled-control

I have multiple css classes that make up a button using SCSS.

```
.ghost-button {
// CSS goes here
}
.ghost-button-label {
// CSS goes here
}
.plus-circle {
//CSS goes here
}
```

Using Angular I can control the disabled state using the following feature.

```
[class.disabled]="booleanFlag"
```

I wanted to have a disabled state for this button with out having multiple disabled classes like so,

```
.ghost-button.disabled {
// CSS goes here
}
.ghost-button-label.disabled {
// CSS goes here
}
.plus-circle.disabled {
//CSS goes here
}
```

This is an example of what I am trying to do. This did not work for me.

```
.ghost-button .ghost-button-label .plus-circle-position .disabled {
    //CSS goes here
}
```

Here is the markup I use for the button,

```
<div style="padding-top: 10px" (click)="handleClickAdd($event)">
    <div class="ghost-button ghost-button-label icon-custom icon-margin plus-circle plus-circle-position" [class.disabled]="blockAdditions">
        <div>
            <div>Add</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you share a few examples of your markup as well, and how you are expecting it to behave?  Either the output HTML or the angular source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because it means each class is a descendant of the previous:

```css
.ghost-button .ghost-button-label .plus-circle-position .disabled {
    //CSS goes here
}
```

If you're trying to just select that one div with all four classes, just remove the spaces:

```css
.ghost-button.ghost-button-label.plus-circle-position.disabled {
    //CSS goes here
}
```

If you're trying to select any elements that have the disabled class plus one of the three other classes, then you use commas to separate the different combinations:

```css
.ghost-button.disabled,
.ghost-button-label.disabled,
.plus-circle-position.disabled {
   // CSS
}
```

Of course you could just select `.disabled` if you want this CSS applied to every element with the disabled class:

```css
.disabled {
  // CSS
}
```

Just be sure to take into account View Encapsulation. You may need to put this CSS in the global style file `styles.css` if this class exists in more than one component.

---

Just a note, you are not setting the `disabled` state here, you are adding a class with the name "disabled". `disabled` is a boolean attribute you can set via HTML, which you can then select with the pseudo-class `:disabled`.

```css
button:disabled {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<button>Not Disabled</button>
<button disabled>Disabled</button>
```

If this is what you were actually trying to do then in Angular it would be:

```html
[disabled]="booleanFlag"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on all of that! The second example you posted is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can target a disabled element with the `:disabled` pseudo-class  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled

So depending on the relationship between your button/label/plus-circle you should be able to target those as well based on whether the button is disabled. For example, if the button and label are siblings you could do this:

```
.ghost-button:disabled,
.ghost-button:disabled + .ghost-button-label,
.ghost-button:disabled + .plus-circle {
// CSS goes here
}
```

That would only work if the label and circle were siblings that come after the button, if they are before the button, you can't select them that way.

Comment: I tried your solution and I could not get it to work. I do not nest any of the css so I removed the + and put each on its own line with :disabled and still no go.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I got an above solution that worked for me.